# unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int' with Python3

Tags: python

My Python3 code

```
def ask():

    while True:
        try:
            n = input('Input an integer: ')
        except:
            print ('An error occurred! Please try again!')
            continue
        else:
            break


    print ('Thank you, you number squared is: ', n**2)
```

Why do I got error if I want to take a square of number?

```
unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

From command line no problems

```
>>> 3**2
9
```

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: you should convert string  to int `n=int(n)` or `n=int(input('Input an integer: '))`

Comment: The best explanation I've seen of why this is happening for python2 and 3, with solution is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`input` returns a string; `**` requires 2 numbers.

Comment: I have been using python for more than 2 years now but I didn't know this. Thank you